# Jetty Servers Error: "Config does not exist: file:///etc/realm.properties"

Tags: java, macos, jsp, embedded-jetty

I am trying to get a Jetty Server to start, however I keep getting this error. I do not understand where it wants me to make/move the etc folder and realm.properties file? (assuming I just copy and paste the ones present in the jetty package) could someone please explain? I am using version 9.4.48 of Jetty by the way, as the others simply did not work.

Comment: Question already asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73703704/jetty-server-error-config-does-not-exist - (with requests for more information)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt your link is broken

Comment: @AndrewNorman looks like OP deleted the other question.  This question cannot be answered in it's current state, there is far too little information to work with.  No details, no steps to reproduce, just an error message with no context.  All on a version of Jetty that has reached End of Life. (Jetty 9.x is at End of Life)